# Why wasn't bounty awarded for this question?

Tags: support, bounty

According to [bounty description](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) here, following rules apply for if bounty is not awarded explicitly.

1. Bounty period of 7 days and 24 hours grace period should had ended.
2. Answer should be created after bounty has started.
3. Answer should have a minimum score of 2.
4. Half amount if score is 2, full amount if answer is accepted.
5. In case of a tie, oldest answer is chosen automatically.
6. If there is no such answer then no bounty is awarded.

I have answered on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118281/did-brendan-cripple-marcos-santos-on-purpose/118344#118344) which fulfills every rule mentioned for automatic award of bounty because bounty setter didn't award is explicitly.

Why has my answer still not awarded the bounty?

Comment: This doesn't apply in your case, of course, but anecdotally, I have in the past deleted an answer of mine that I felt didn't warrant the bounty, then reinstated it after the grace period had expired. There can be unfortunate side effects of not specifically awarding the bounty - that the system automatically hands it to the one with most upvotes… which can be the only answer, even if wrong. As a bounty setter you cannot revoke this by any means. This once resulted in a huge bounty going to a completely wrong answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been awarded 2 hours ago.

Perhaps it was caching or [site maintenance activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381305/321725) that it was awarded late.

The bounty wouldn't always be awarded at the exact time. It may take a little time, like one hour or so.

Comment: Yeah, the timings in the docs really relate to how the manual award of the bounty is concerned.  I am not at all surprised that it might take an hour of two for automatic awards to be calculated - I'm not entirely sure how SE does this, but it wouldn't surprise me if it were a job executed a few times a day, and not continually.

Comment: Looks like site maintenance collided with expiration of grace period for bounty.

Comment: @iandotkelly Yep. I am not sure when their automatic scripts run. It could be either per minute or per hour. I have seen the bounty being awarded within an hour though. However, it never gets awarded at the exact time the bounty expires as far as I saw